# How can I intercept the methods of .net framework class library?[C#]

Tags: c#, attributes, intercept

I want to log some info by programming before and after the SQL Server driver really creating the connection(not get connection from the connection pool).

I read the source code of .net framework and find that CreateNonPooledConnection and CreatePooledConnection method of class DbConnectionFactory in System.Data.dll are the right place to intercept.

I searched and found Cauldron.Interception.Fody.
I defined a custom attribute. It can be easily put on the method of my own class and works fine.

```
[InterceptorOptions(AlwaysCreateNewInstance = true)]
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = false)]
public class MyInterceptorAttribute : Attribute, IMethodInterceptor
{
    public void OnEnter(Type declaringType, object instance, MethodBase methodbase, object[] values)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("OnEnter");
    }

    public bool OnException(Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        return false;
    }

    public void OnExit()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("OnExit");
    }

}


[MyInterceptor]
internal void CreateConnection()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Create connection.");
}
```

The output is:

> OnEnter
>
> Create connection.
>
> OnExit

But how can I put my custom attribute into the methods of .net framework class library,or any other ways to achieve my goal?

Comment: What have you [tried so far](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: I tried the Cauldron,which is one of the fody addins,with no luck.A build error occurs and I proposed an issue to the Cauldron.

Comment: It would be very helpful for others to help you, if you try to put needed information in your question text, see also: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Thanks for your advice.